# Reloading a UITableView on a UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller set up as follows:

UIViewController

In IB I have set set a UITableView to have the File's Owner (the UIViewController) be both its delegate and data source. When I Build & Go, I can trace the table view methods (for sections and rows) being called so the connections seem to be OK through the view loading.

But... when I populate some arrays at the end of viewDidLoad and then try to call [self reloadData], it terminates. I'm seeing many posts around this area but none have quite hit the spot for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[self reloadData]` in your case sends a message to UIViewController.
You should be doing this instead..
`[self.tableView reloadData]` (or whatever outlet you have connected to your table view)

(Just saw the date :P... anyway, just for contributing to knowledge base)